# How can I import into a script from a publics folder in React Chrome Extension?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, create-react-app, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, npm-build

I'm creating a Chrome extension with React using CRA.

I have some scripts that I need to run on specific pages. If I put them in the `/src` folder, they are not found when I run the extension because of the `npm run build` command.

For version 3 of the `manifest.json` file, the `background.js`, `profileEnhancer.js`, etc. must be in the same folder as the `manifest.json` file, or they will not be found.

Any suggestions on how to move `manifest.json` and background.js into the `/src` folder and still have it build properly with `npm run build`, or a way use import in the public folder?

Current Folder Structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQQpp.png)

i am trying to import:

```
import XLSX from 'xlsx';
```

In the script `profileEnhancer.js`, but it gives the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

If I place all the scripts in the src folder and then build the project to run the extension, the script is not found when it is called due to a localization change. I attempted to rename the scripts to .mjs and added the "type: module" attribute, but it resulted in an error.

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
target: { tabId: details.tabId },
files: ["./js/profileEnhancer.js"],
module: true
```

I also tried using Babel to create a transpiled version of the script called "profileEnhancer-transpiled.js," but it didn't work. I didn't fully understand how to use it.